# Google drive api, php sdk: get uploaded file information with resumable upload?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How can I get something equivalent to the information generated by   $service->files->insert() when simple upload is used, when using resumable uploads. Currently it returns a http request object which is useless.

Comment: what information do you need? Remember that in Drive, creating the file (insert) is a very different action to uploading content to that file. They are distinct phases of the create-a-file procedure

Comment: @pinoyyid I need the file ID when I'm done uploading, so I can download/delete/edit at willl

Comment: I'm not sure what information I'm getting and were it is...